# ORA-00911 What am I doing wrong? Oracle

Tags: sql, database, oracle, ora-00911

Here is my code:

```
DROP TABLE cover_resp;
DROP TABLE cover;
DROP TABLE absence;
DROP TABLE sickness;

select constraint_name, constraint_type, table_name
from user_constraints
where table_name IN ('SICKNESS' , 'ABSENCE' , 'COVER' , 'COVER_RESP')
```

What am I doing wrong? I keep getting the same ORA-00911 error message.

Comment: What front-end program do you use to interact with the database? SQL\*Plus? SQL Developer? Toad? Something else? Regardless, the error message contains many more details - how they are displayed depends on your front-end, but they all should include the same information. What is the complete error message? Also: I hope you expect the result of your query to be empty (zero rows returned). Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: Are you trying to run all five statements within one PreparedStatement or so?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing Seems to be wrong with your code. However ORA:000911 stands for invalid character.

Try to retype your code and run it again.

Answer (score 0):

a typical situation is the "non-breaking" space which looks like a normal space, but is a different character. On a Mac, you get it woth [Option] + Space. Whenever something like this is in your code, you will get the ORA-911 ...

Hope that helps